# Add "NET START" permission to program?

Tags: mysql, windows, intellij-idea, xampp, windows-services

I am hosting a MySQL server on windows via xampp and want to start it whenever I test my Intellij application.

Intellij provides a way to run commands before starting the application, so I added

```
NET START MySQL
```

When starting, the console says:

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

Answers from other Threads include running cmd as an administrator, but since Intellij runs the commands in the internal "Terminal", I can't really do that without running Intellij as admin every time.

Now my question is, can I grant Intellij some sort of permission to use NET?

Comment: But of course you have to be an admin to make that change, are you, or will your admins allow you that access

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, that worked!